# How to to always force 'Run Without Debugging' to Output to the Debug Console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have searched quite a bit  for this and have not been able to find an answer.

I have been coming across quite allot of inconsistent behaviour with the **Run Without Debugging** command.

Whether, the **Run Without Debugging** command will output to the Integrated Terminal or the Debugging Console  seems to be subject to the currently active `launch.json` configuration in the **Run and Debug** panel.

For example if the active configuration is the following, **Run Without Debugging** uses the Debug Console:

```
 ...
{
    "name": "PYconsole",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "program": "${file}"
}
  ...
```

Or if the active configuration is the following, **Run Without Debugging** uses the Integrated Terminal:

```
...
{
    "name": "PYterminal",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "program": "${file}"
}
...
```

I find this leading to completely unexpected behaviours randomly.

Is it the expected behaviour that in order to output to the Debugging Console with **Run Without Debugging**, I have to make sure a configuration that uses `"console": "internalConsole"`, is active on **Run and Debug** panel?

Furthermore, in the cases of there not being a `launch.json` file defined for a particular workspace, what setting is deciding whether the Integrated Terminal or the Debugging Console will be used, when **Run Without Debugging** is invoked?

In my case, The Integrated Terminal is being used, I would like the Debugging Console to be used instead.

I am on the latest VSCode version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!